# Store returning values in separate variables-Python

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

I am learning Python right now. I just wanted to know. Is it possible, if you return 3 values from a function can you store them in 3 separate variables?

```
def convert_second(seconds):
  hours = seconds // 3600
  minutes = (seconds - hours * 3600) // 60
  remaining_seconds = seconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60
  return hours, minutes, remaining_seconds

duration = convert_second(5000)
print(duration)
```

Comment: You mean `hours, minutes, seconds = convert_second(5000)`?

Comment: FWIW this function doesn't return 3 values. It returns a single tuple

Comment: @DeepSpace the single tuple contains 3 values which can be unpacked as above

Comment: @MuhdMairaj A single tuple is still a single value. The function returns a single value.

Comment: @DeepSpace  Nevermind, i thought you replied to the first comment in this chain. But i see now that you corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this:

```
def convert_second(seconds):
  hours = seconds // 3600
  minutes = (seconds - hours * 3600) // 60
  remaining_seconds = seconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60
  return hours, minutes, remaining_seconds

hours, minutes, remaining_seconds = convert_second(5000)

print(f"{hours= }",f"{minutes= }",f"{remaining_seconds= }")
```

prints:

```
hours= 1 minutes= 23 remaining_seconds= 20
```

Comment: What is this 'f' called inside the print function?

Comment: nice example for unpacking.  For someone new to python, also look at returning a dict so you could use a single formatted string `"hours= {hours} minutes= {minutes} remaining seconds= {remaining_seconds}".format(convert_second(5000))`

Comment: the leading "f" means it is a formatted string.  My previous comment is the old-school way to make a string and calling the formatting function on it.  They are equivalent.  f-strings are extremely powerful tools.

Comment: Yes, it is an fstring, Read more at https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, just use the code below:

```
def convert_second(seconds):
  hours = seconds // 3600
  minutes = (seconds - hours * 3600) // 60
  remaining_seconds = seconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60
  return hours, minutes, remaining_seconds

duration_hours, duration_minutes, duration_seconds = convert_second(5000)
print(duration_hours, duration_minutes, duration_seconds)
```